# Extracting frame referencing information in h264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, decoding, x264

I'm trying to extract the frame (slice) information from the mp4 file that contains the h264 encoded media. Especially, I need the slice size, slice type, DTS, reference frame list.

Through the stss box and stsz box, I can extract the information about the size, type.

However, I cannot find any information about how to extract the reference frame list for the certain . Which field or box should I look into for extracting frame referencing information? (For example, in case of B frame, the B frame refers the other frames frame 3 and 4)

The main reason of extracting these information is that I am trying to construct the frame dependency map. (e,g Frame A which is 15235 bytes size needs Frame B, C for decoding, Frame B's size is 4222 bytes and need frame D ...etc)

Thanks.

Comment: That data is not encoded into the mp4. You will need to parse the video frames themselves.

Comment: @szatmary Can I extract those information through ffmpeg?  Right now, I am trying to extract motionvectors and parse it. However, it also doesn't contain the referencing info. Could you please let me know which API or data structure should I use for extracting the referencing info?